# Local website not working

Tags: apache

I'm having a *lot* of trouble setting up a local website that I need to do some work on.

I have 2 local sites: "first_training" and "resus_skills"

The former, first_training, works. I have it set up that `first_training.loc/` takes me to the local site. resus_skills is set up in the exact same way, but when I try to access `resus_skills.loc/` all I get is:

[image]

Here are the details of my setup, as well as some screenshots of it:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/resus_skills.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName resus_skills.loc
    ServerAlias www.resus_skills.loc
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/resus_skills"
    <Directory "/var/www/resus_skills">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I made sure to enable it with `sudo a2ensite resus_skills.conf` and have confirmed that it's symlink is present in ``/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

I've made sure my apache server is running:

[image]

and I've run `apachectl -S` to get this result:

[image]

I am able to reach first_training.loc/ with no issues, but cannot reach resus_skills.loc/.

I'm unsure how to troubleshoot this - the apache error.log isn't showing me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Before anyone points out what an idiot I've been - I never updated the `/etc/hosts` file, which was the only missing step.